# Jquery Droppable Items from Explorer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

does the droppable UI in jquery will support dropping items from explorer? like i will drag a picture from my drive to a DIV element.. :)

Comment: You can drop file elements on to a file input, it is then possible to do other things with them.

Comment: BUt dear friend you will be able to reap the benefits when you will use draggable and droppable together

Comment: would you mind if i can see it in action.. :) like a sample code.. i can't really figure out how to in jquery..

Comment: @Jatin Dhoot.. yep.. im using those UI elements.. but what i was trying is dragging a file from explorer to a browser then drop to a DIV element.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those both UI parts don't support dragging and dropping from the desktop.

However, it is quite trivial to add support for dropping images on your website. You can follow this article on the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop#Drag_and_drop_basics and use getDataURL on the File instance you receive :-)